# Regex lazy solution for java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string "`hooRayNexTcapItaLnextcapitall`"
I want to capture the first instance of "`next`" (`NexT` - in this case)

My soultion:

```
(.*)([nN][eE][xX][tT])([cC][aA][pP][iI][tT][aA][lL])(.*)
```

My solution group1 returns `next` instead of `Next`

How can I correct my regex to capture the first next instead of capturing the last next?

Edit 1:
Let me put my question properly,

If the string contains any combination of upper and lower case letters that spell "NextCapital", reverse the characters of the word "Next". Case should be preserved. If "NextCapital" occurs multiple times, only update the first occurrence.

So, I am using group to capture. But my group is capturing the last occurrence of "nextCapital" instead of first occurrence.

Ex: 
Input: hooRayNexTcapItaLnextcapitall
output: hooRayTxeNcapItaLnextcapitall

Edit 2: 
Please correct my code.
My java code:

```
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("(.*)([nN][eE][xX][tT])([cC][aA][pP][iI][tT][aA][lL])(.*)");
            //sb = hooRayNexTcapItaLnextcapitall
            Matcher mtc = ptn.matcher(sb);
            StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
            if(mtc.find()){
                StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder e = new StringBuilder();

                d.append(mtc.group(1));
                e.append(mtc.group(2));
                e.reverse();
                d.append(e);
                d.append(mtc.group(3));
                d.append(mtc.group(4));
                sb = d;
            }
```

Comment: Let's see your code.  Perhaps there's an error causing you to view the second match rather than your regex being bad.

Comment: @phatfingers I have posted my code above. Can you check it? I am looking for regex solution.

Comment: You were one character off from having working code.  I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex actually works if you get group 2. Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/mQDc24/1)! Your regex does not need to be that complicated.

Your regex can just be this:

```
next
```

If you use `Matcher.find` and turn on `CASE_INSENSITIVE` option, you can find the first substring of the string that matches the pattern. Then, use `group()` to get the actual string:

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("next", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("hooRayNexTcapItaLnextcapitall");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

EDIT:

After seeing your requirements, I wrote this code:

```
String input = "hooRayNexTcapItaLnextcapitall";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("next(?=capital)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);
    StringBuilder reverseBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    outputBuilder.replace(m.start(), m.end(), reverseBuilder.reverse().toString());
    System.out.println(outputBuilder);
}
```

I used a lookahead to match `next` only if there is `capital` after it. After a match is found, I created a string builder with the input, and another string builder with the *matched portion* of the input. Then, I replaced the matched range with the reverse of the second string builder.

Comment: Can you please check the question again. I have edited it and made the problem statement clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
String target = "next";
int index = line.toLowerCase().indexOf(target);
if (index != -1) {
    line = line.substring(index, index + target.length());
    System.out.println(line);
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```

This would be my first attempt which allows room for adjusting the desired String to locate.

Otherwise you may use this ReGeX solution to achieve the same effect:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)next");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The pattern "(?i)next" finds the substring matching "next" ignoring case.

**Edit** : This would reverse the order of the first occurrence of next.

```
String input = "hooRayNexTcapItaLnextcapitall";
String target = "nextcapital";
int index = input.toLowerCase().indexOf(target);
if (index != -1) {
    String first = input.substring(index, index + target.length());
    first = new StringBuilder(first.substring(0, 4)).reverse().toString() + first.substring(4, first.length());
    input = input.substring(0, index) + first + input.substring(index + target.length(), input.length());
}
```

**Edit Again** : Here is a "fixed" form of your code.

```
        String input = "hooRayNexTcapItaLnextcapitall";
        Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("([nN][eE][xX][tT])([cC][aA][pP][iI][tT][aA][lL])");
        Matcher mtc = ptn.matcher(input);
        if(mtc.find()){
            StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder(mtc.group(1));
            StringBuilder e = new StringBuilder(mtc.group(2));
            input = input.replaceFirst(d.toString() + e.toString(), d.reverse().toString() + e.toString());
            System.out.println(input);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please check the question again. I have edited it and made the problem statement clear.

Comment: Updated. It's a little clunky so you may want to separate into various methods (Like reverseOrder(String s, int start, int end) to reverse the order of the chars).

Comment: Can you correct my java code? I am interested in regex solution. I have posted my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is grabbing the second potential match for your group due to the default greedy nature of regex.  Effectively, the first `(.*)` is grabbing as much as it can while still satisfying the rest of your regex.

To get what you intend, you can add a question mark to the first group, making it `(.*?)`.  This will make it non-greedy, grabbing the smallest string possible while still satisfying the rest of your regex.